# How to exchange the links's place using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

How to exchange the links's place using jquery.

below the navigation will be content div for each tab. the selected link will always next to the first "sixrevision" link.

[image]

Code will be like this

```
   <ul id="crumbs">
   <li><a href="#" class="selected">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">product 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">product 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">product 1</a></li>   
   /ul>
```

It will be a ajax tab system but only tabs looks like breadcrumb. I want to know how to keep "selected" item always in next of first item.

Comment: I want to integrate in this tabs http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a slightly different approach, and it is outlined below and demonstrated at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSKVR/ZnHpy/1/) (try clicking the links in the example)

The advantages to this is that the change can be initiated by pure CSS. You do not need to change HTML or apply javascript if you are doing a server-side change. I personally find this to be cleaner and easier to manage in the long run.

NOTE: I changed the HTML slightly, to have the containing **li** element fashion the 'selected' class, opposed to the **a** element. I have found that applying 'selected' and 'active' classes to the containing elements, opposed to the click element, allows for more flexibility.

**HTML**

```
 <ul id="crumbs">
   <li><a href="#">XHTML</a></li>
   <li class="selected"><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Flash</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>   
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('ul#crumbs li a').bind('click',crumbClick)
});

function crumbClick(){
    $('ul#crumbs .selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');
    return false;
}
```

**CSS [for example]**

```
/* RESET */
ul#crumbs, ul#crumbs li { margin:0;padding:0;}

ul#crumbs li a {display:inline-block;padding:3px 4px;}

ul#crumbs li {list-style:none;display:inline;}

ul#crumbs li.selected {float:left;}
```

Comment: I tried with my case. styling is changing but place not. my css is different than yours.

Comment: And in IE 7 your example doesn't work properly, link goes down upon click. But your script is really great. I need one more thing. I want to keep 1st list item not affected. How to do that?

Comment: In terms of the first element, are you talking about 'SixRevisions' in your example graphic? The contents of the UL are strictly for reordering. So the solution, in accordance with my design pattern, is to place the **stand-still** element, or the *title* or *label* outside of the UL.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) the `.selected` one to move it to being the first child, like this:

```
$("#crumbs .selected").prependTo("#crumbs");
```

Comment: @Jitendra - I don't follow the question...can you clarify a bit?

Comment: Sorry that was typo. mistake. I was asking do you know any website which is using the effect like I'm asking.

Comment: @Jitendra - oh, not that I'm aware of...but of course you wouldn't notice either.  If you're doing it onclick...I wouldn't, people don't like their buttons moving on them.  If you're doing it onload...which is what I assumed from the question, then most would do this server-side before the client gets any HTML.

Comment: I want to integrate that effect in tab like this http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/tabs/ in this example you assume "Gallery" as "sixrevision" according to my attached image. if i click on "Contact" it should exchange the place with "submit"